# recognize gesture in a QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, gesture, qquickitem

I want to create some gestures for my `QQuickPaintedItem`
In the normal QWidgets we have the method `gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)` ([look here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gestures-imagegestures.html))

But how can I get these events in a QQuickItem?

Comment: What about doing it in QML? "Qt.labs.gestures 1.0" provides useful items that will allow you to work with gestures.

Comment: Sorry, I want to put that stuff in my own c++ plugin. Of course, I can link the items from qml to c++, but maybe there is another way?